# I am having trouble with this error (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize' in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, keras

I am trying to apply a Keras' image classifier to my project, but down the road I got stuck with this. Though previously, with the same code I could use OpenCV to read and train images, but after switching to a new batch of images it got caught with the error. So my speculation is that there's something wrong with my file type:

This is from the batch that got the error:

> traf.204.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio,
> density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 480x294, frames
> 1

This is from the batch that didn't get caught with the error:

> bear.290.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio,
> density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 224x224, frames
> 3

But the file type seems to be exactly the same (except for the resolution). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code as well where it threw error.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was supposed to add a try/exception so my code could bypass "ugly" images:

```
try:
    path=os.path.join(mypath, n)
    img=cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img=cv2.resize(img, (img_rows, img_cols))

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

*cv2.resize()* was where it was supposed to catch the error since it couldn't resize a "broken" image.

Answer (score 10):

One more possibility: `width` or `height` of the image might be zero:

```
print(image.shape())
# (300, 0) -> Incorrect!
# (0, 400) -> Incorrect!

# (300, 400) -> Correct!
# (400, 300) -> Correct!
```

This might happen when you try to resize an image **after applying some image processing techniques** (say, using OpenCV) and, **height or width of your image may become 0**.

Comment: That was it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Just enter the precise image format. *.jpg* instead of *.jpeg*.

Comment: What does the spelling of the filename suffix have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were special characters in the file name. Like "ü", "ä", "/", etc.

I had to make a choice: Renaming automatically or just raise an error for the user to know, that the pictures have bad names.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because after resizing an image the height or width becomes 0.
I had tackled this by just printing the image name before resizing. So I can get to the root cause that due to which image this issue is occurring and just deleted that image from my dataset.
Below is the code how I solved this using debugging:

```
# loop over the input images
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    print(imagePath)  #here I have printed the imagename
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))   # 28, 28
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had my camera app open in Windows 10, and that's why I was getting that error. I shut it down and reran my code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to wrong image type passed while resizing an image. 
The solution is to add a check before resizing the image:

```
if type(image):
    image = cv2.resize(image, (h, w), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem because I was reading multiple images from a directory and that directory had a pdf file(silly), so make sure your specified paths have only images.

Answer (score -1):

Put double backslashes in your path inside the *imread* function.